# How to upload image in CKEditor in Laravel with server side image uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins

I try to upload ckeditor local image to database using Laravel. My code as following:

```
 {{ Form::textarea('description','',array('class'=>'form-control
  ckeditor ','data-required'=>'1','required'=>'true'))}}
```

My script is

```
 <script src="{{
 URL::to('admin_asset/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="{{ URL::to('admin_asset/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this full URL in your controller in return statements

**return " parent.setImageValue('".$url."'); ";**

Comment: Thank you keval its really help full

Comment: walcome @RavindraBhanderi it's my  pleasure